# Pre-commenting R output

Tags: r

I was curious...  Is there a good wrapper function or something similar that will cause R to comment out the output from a call to `print()`?

I often like including example output in my SO posts, but adding the necessary formatting by hand gets tedious.

I just duct-taped together a function for it...

```
so <- function(x) {
  out <- paste0('\n',"    # ",capture.output(x))
  cat(out)
}
```

...such that

```
so(1:4)

# [1] 1 2 3 4

so(data.frame(x=rnorm(6),y=rnorm(6)))

#             x          y 
# 1 -1.41322737  0.9892096 
# 2  0.06482021 -0.4459670 
# 3  0.86084224 -1.1174499 
# 4  0.64835059 -0.4408597 
# 5 -1.81053085  0.6771153 
# 6 -0.96065397 -0.5877505

so(summary(lm(y~x, data=data.frame(x=rnorm(6),y=rnorm(6)))))

#  
# Call: 
# lm(formula = y ~ x, data = data.frame(x = rnorm(6), y = rnorm(6))) 
#  
# Residuals: 
#        1        2        3        4        5        6  
# -1.36705  0.08917 -0.20441  1.15421  0.15772  0.17036  
#  
# Coefficients: 
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) 
# (Intercept)  -0.2762     0.3957  -0.698    0.524 
# x             0.5925     0.6310   0.939    0.401 
#  
# Residual standard error: 0.9089 on 4 degrees of freedom 
# Multiple R-squared:  0.1806,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.0242  
# F-statistic: 0.8818 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.4009 
#
```

...but there was an alarm going off in my head saying there *must* be a better way.

Is there?

Comment: Seems like a good solution to me. Not sure which part you want to be "better"? What you've done seems pretty simple.

Comment: Simple, yes... but was curious if there was something that already existed in base R, and that was robust to wonky cases.

Comment: Can you give one such "wonky" case where this would not work?

Comment: Probably not - just didn't want to assume there wasn't something I hadn't thought about.  Thanks!

Comment: @MattTyers I think it'd be better if you edit this and make it in an QA style (ask a question and answer it yourself). Liked your function btw.

Comment: Try using the "Knit Document" menu command in Rstudio.  The document output will have the R output commented

Comment: I think `soanswer` from the `overflow` package does something similar: https://github.com/mrdwab/overflow-mrdwab

Comment: You might consider the `reprex` package, which does essentially the same thing as your function, but has the advantage of being prepared bundled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to those who weighed in - I'll post this as an answer in case someone has the same question down the road.

There were two suggestions that I particularly liked - `soanswer()` from the `overflow` package, and `reprex()` from the `reprex` package.

**the 'overflow' package**

`soanswer()` is very simple, and prints pre-commented text to the console, along with whatever let up to the `print()` call.  Hence,

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(6),y=rnorm(6))
soanswer(df)
```

prints

```
df
##            x          y
## 1  0.1817694  2.0660698
## 2 -0.5104673  2.5531193
## 3  0.1161377 -0.1783387
## 4 -2.3018991 -0.8449460
## 5  2.0201924 -0.5774678
## 6 -1.2148632  1.7873003
```

directly to the console.  It comes with a few friends, like `soread()` and `sodput()` that look super useful.  I couldn't find `overflow` on CRAN, so installed from Github via `devtools::install_github("mrdwab/overflow-mrdwab")`

**the 'reprex' package**

`reprex()` acts as a wrapper for an entire REPRoducible EXample, and will complain if you reference objects that aren't within it.  Usage looks like

```
reprex({
  df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(6),y=rnorm(6))
  df + 1
}, venue="so")
```

and this renders

```
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(6), y = rnorm(6))
df + 1
#>           x         y
#> 1 0.9632665 0.8067071
#> 2 1.2540641 0.6184877
#> 3 0.2663705 0.9305724
#> 4 2.2675316 1.1118192
#> 5 1.7843500 2.6724034
#> 6 0.5396790 1.9320059
```

to the clipboard.  I found this very cool, but still had to indent it by hand.

**In summary**, I found that the `overflow` package was more tailored to what I wanted to do (and this is what I'll most likely use in the future), but was glad to find out about `reprex`.

Comment: I liked your function as it also adds the leading spaces. Not Sure if `overflow` package does the same.